# How to get a variable from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

How can I access to a variable from my controller and use it in my page? This is the code of my controller:

```
public ActionResult Agence(AgenceQuery model)
{
    var result = Test.Areas.Admin.Models.WebUser.GetUser(model.Num_RA);
    if (result == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Cette agence n'éxiste pas");
        return View();
    }

    return View();
}
```

And thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: You need to learn about Models.

Comment: i'm just a beginner. can you please help me?

Comment: If you want to pass model back to the page use strongly typed view and pass `View(result)`. In case if you need to pass some additional data to your view, send it in a `ViewBag`

Comment: and how can i access to them from my page ?

Comment: Please spend some time on http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: Check out a tutorial. There's plenty on www.asp.net

Comment: the problem is i don't have enough time, i have just this issue

Comment: @Amranze There is no need to add Resolved to your title. Your green checkmark on the answer is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ViewBag.Result = result;
```

And in your view:

```
@ViewBag.Result.FieldThatYouWantToDisplay
```

Or

```
ViewData["Result"] = result;
```

And in your view:

```
@ViewData["Result"].FieldThatYouWantToDisplay
```

Or

```
return View(result)
```

And in your view:

```
@model Full.Path.To.The.Type.Of.Result.Variable

@Model.FieldThatYouWantToDisplay
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewBag](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-ViewBag.html)

In the Controller

```
public ActionResult Agence(AgenceQuery model)
{
    var result = Test.Areas.Admin.Models.WebUser.GetUser(model.Num_RA);
    if (result == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "CustomError, Cette agence n'éxiste pas";
    }

    return View();
}
```

in the View, retrieve it :

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error)
```

Comment: for the error i have a solution, but the main issue is the variable "result"